# Smaller annotation in button

Tags: html, css

so I'd like the below button to have a small annotation (smaller font) below its main text but for the solutions, I've tried to resize the entire button and put

```css
.kafelek {
            background-color: #C3CECB;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 230px;
            height: 100px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans';
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #003C3D;
            margin-top: 15px;
            margin-bottom: 1px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-left: 0px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

            .kafelek:nth-child(5) {
                margin-right: 150px !important;
            }

            .kafelek:nth-child(6) {
                margin-left: 150px !important;
            }

            .kafelek:hover {
                border: 2px solid #7EDF00;
                transition: 0.3s;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
```

```html
  <div class="kafelek">COMING SOON <div class="smallannot"> (Annotation) </div> </div>
```

the text on the right side instead of just starting a new line.

I've tried defining a new class with a smaller font size but it breaks the button entirely (the text doesn't align properly)

Answer (score 0):

Use this `CSS`, adding `flex-direction: column` to the code helps to align the text vertically.

```
.kafelek {
        flex-direction : column;
    }
```

After doing so you will get this result,

```css
.kafelek {
  background-color: #C3CECB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #003C3D;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.kafelek:nth-child(5) {
  margin-right: 150px !important;
}

.kafelek:nth-child(6) {
  margin-left: 150px !important;
}

.kafelek:hover {
  border: 2px solid #7EDF00;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="kafelek">COMING SOON
  <div class="smallannot"> (Annotation) </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use flex simply create a container representing the button and then avoid nesting the divs. They'll be displayed one under the other.

You can tweak padding/margin to get the design you want. Furthermore, the transition doesn't go on the hover, it goes on the element being hovered.

```css
.kafelek {
    background-color: #C3CECB;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 230px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #003C3D;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.soon {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
        
.kafelek:hover {
    background-color: #c6f7ea;
    border: 2px solid #7EDF00;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="kafelek">
  <div class="soon">COMING SOON</div>
  <div class="smallannot"> (Annotation) </div>
</div>
```